# When I try to simulate VHDL code, the signals do not work, losses, show a orange color

Tags: simulation, vhdl

I'm using a Nexys 3 Spartan 6 Lower Power XC6SLX16L.

The idea of the program is with a timer counter with specific conditions with the bottoms.

Here is my code:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity structural is
    Port ( 
          up : in STD_LOGIC;
          down : in STD_LOGIC;
          right : in STD_LOGIC;
          left : in STD_LOGIC;
          reset : in STD_LOGIC;
          clock : in STD_LOGIC;
          anodes : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
          cathodes : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0)
    );
end structural;

architecture behavioral of structural is
  signal clock_dis, clock_pul: std_logic;
  signal pun1, pun2, pun3, code: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin
  slowClockProcess: process(clock)
    variable countFastCycles: integer range 0 to 50000 := 0;  -- Divide the frequency by half
    variable countFastCycles3: integer range 0 to 5000000 := 0;  -- Divide the frequency by half
  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      countFastCycles := countFastCycles + 1;
      countFastCycles3 := countFastCycles3 + 1;
    
      if countFastCycles = 50000 then
        clock_dis <= NOT clock_dis; -- Generate rising/falling edge for displays
        countFastCycles := 0;
      end if;
    
      if countFastCycles3 = 5000000 then
        clock_pul <= NOT clock_pul; -- Generate rising/falling edge for buttons
        countFastCycles3 := 0;
      end if; 
    end if;
  end process slowClockProcess;

  count: process(up, down, right, left, reset, clock)
    variable counter: integer := 0;
  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      if reset = '1' then
        counter := 0; -- Reset the counter
      else
        if up = '1' then
          counter := counter + 1;
        end if;
       
        -- Decrement the counter
        if down = '1' then
          counter := counter - 1;
        end if;
        
        -- Increment the counter by 10 units
        if right = '1' then
          counter := counter + 10;
        end if;
        
        -- Decrement the counter by 10 units
        if left = '1' then
          counter := counter - 10;
        end if;

        -- Ensure the counter is within the range [0, 999]
        if counter < 0 then
          counter := 0;
        elsif counter > 999 then
          counter := 999;
        end if;
        
        pun1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(counter / 100, 4));
        pun2 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned((counter / 10) mod 10, 4));  
        pun3 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(counter mod 10, 4));
      end if;
    end if;
  end process count;

  seqDisplayProcess: process(clock)
    variable numDisplay: integer range 0 to 4 := 0;
  begin
    if rising_edge(clock_dis) then
      if numDisplay = 0 then
        anodes <= "1011";
        code <= pun1;
      elsif numDisplay = 1 then
        anodes <= "1101";
        code <= pun2;
      elsif numDisplay = 2 then
        anodes <= "1110";
        code <= pun3;
      else
        anodes <= "1111";
        code <= "0000";
      end if;
      
      numDisplay := numDisplay + 1;
      
      if numDisplay > 3 then
        numDisplay := 0;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process seqDisplayProcess;

  -- BCD to 7-segment decoder
  cathodes <= "00000011" when code = "0000" else -- Display number 0
              "10011111" when code = "0001" else -- Display number 1
              "00100101" when code = "0010" else -- Display number 2
              "00001101" when code = "0011" else -- Display number 3
              "10011001" when code = "0100" else -- Display number 4
              "01001001" when code = "0101" else -- Display number 5
              "01000001" when code = "0110" else -- Display number 6
              "00011111" when code = "0111" else -- Display number 7
              "00000001" when code = "1000" else -- Display number 8
              "00001001" when code = "1001" else -- Display number 9 
              "00000000";  -- Default case
end behavioral;
```

The signals are losses, and I don't know why:

[image: Simulation error]

I didn't find a syntax error. I tried changing everything.

Comment: I never had code producing orange signals. What does this color mean in your software? The screenshot is not readable at all.

Comment: @asdfex Look at the screenshot in a separate tab. The orange waves are "undefined" (`U`).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you try to simulate your logic without applying a clock signal. All your logic depends on the input clock. Therefore the outputs are necessarily all undefined (`U`).

This matches the reality. For the simulation, you might get away with initial values.

The solution is to provide a test bench that stimulates the inputs of your logic. Before you start to write it, think about what you like to test.